# How to determine if a Carry Look Ahead Adder Overflows

Tags: digital-logic, adder, carry-look-ahead

I am implementing a 32 bit CLA Adder like how a 16 bit adder is implemented in Wikipedia

[image]

Problem is how do I determine if the block overflows? I will need the carry into bit 32 (which is now in the last 4 bit CLA Adder) and XOR with carry out of bit 32(Check difference in MSB)?

**UPDATE**

Is my overflow logic correct

[image]

where Cin is the carry into the whole 16 bit block, P* is the Block Propagate, G* the block generate, and carry into bit 32 (typo, bit 16 MSB actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about seeing what my brain could regurgitate of long ago explnatins, as opposed to commin sense observations, BUT here's [a page which does it all very well indeed](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/overflow.html).

They explain a "nice" 'trick'.

- Two's compelment overflow detection can be achieved by XORing the carry-in and the carry-out bo=its of the leftmost full adder.

Their diagram. See above ref for detailed comment:

[image]

Comment: Thats a 1 bit adder, the problem with using a >1 bit adder is that the carry into the MSB is hidden somewhere in the adder itself. Hope you got me? I could have an output for my block adder for Cin to MSB but that seems off place? Alternatively, I could have evey block output an Overflow bit, is this the usual implementation? It will give quite abit redundant logic

Comment: The last stage output is the XOR of the two inputs and the carry in; thus the carry in is the xor of the two inputs and the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing the CLA (carry lookahead adder) block, you could have the block output the carry from the bit 2 digit (which must already be calculated in order to form the correct value for bit 3 of the sum).

If the CLA block interface is a given, you can derive overflow from the sign bits of the two adder inputs, A(31) and B(31), and the sign bit of the output sum.  If A and B are the same sign, the sum sign must match them iff there is no overflow.  For more detail, see [this page](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_2/5.html) or [this page](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Comb/overflow.html).

Answer (score 1):

**You can retrace C(n-1) from P, G and S**

If you use: **X = XOR( P, G)**

or you can also use XOR( !P, !G); P=Propagate, G=Generate

**Ci(n-1) = XOR( X, S)**
; S = sum result of highest bit

Now you have Ci(n-1) and Ci(n)

**V = XOR ( Ci(n-1), Ci(n) )** ; see other theories above

|  |  |  |  | G= | P= | X= | Ci= | Ci |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AxB | =Y | xCi | =S | A&B | A+B | GxP | XxS | check |
| 00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ok |
| 11 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ok |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | ok |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ok |

*x = XOR; + = OR; & = AND; ! = NOT*
[image]